# Unexpected caching svg d3 forced directed graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, svg, tornado

I am developing a math learning tool at provemath.org.  If you login and click on a vertex and click the light bulb to "learn" it, then go back to the main graph, you will see that the vertex is now darker in color (it is now stored in `user.learned_node_ids` in the javascript and also on the server).

If you then RELOAD the page, the vertex appears unlearned again (BAD).  Also, if you open a new tab and go to provemath.org, you get the same result.  I have verified that the data is correct on the server.  Also, if you open a different browser, there is no problem.

My best guess, therefore, is that there is some weird caching going on.  When I develop locally, I use cachbusting to make sure that javascript files don't get cached.  So I feel that there could be some weird javascript global variable caching (i don't think so) or more likely, some HTML svg caching.  The svg elements on the page are populated by the javascript, they are not originally in the HTML file.  Is there some SVG caching I should know about?

Any troubleshooting ideas?

UPDATE: It is difficult to create a jsfiddle because 1. I don't know which part of the code is responsible and 2. the project is very big.  Instead, I'll show some snippets below of what I think is the most relevant code, and I'll provide a [link](https://github.com/ProveMath/prove-math) to the code repository.

I'm looking for theoretical ideas of what might cause this, and then I'll be able to delve deeper.

`graph-animation.js` runs the d3 force-directed graph. Excerpts:

// create SVG tag:

```
gA.svg = d3.select('body') // select() only seems to work on 'body', but not on any '#id's!!!! :(
        .append('svg')
            .attr({
                viewBox: '0' + ' ' + '0' + ' ' + gA.width() + ' ' + gA.height(),
            })
```

// draw or redraw/update SVG links and circles/nodes/vertices:

```
function update() { // this function gets called AGAIN when new nodes come in
    let link = gA.svg.selectAll('.link').data(gA.force.links(), generateLinkId) // links before nodes so that lines in SVG appear *under* nodes
    link.enter().append('line')
        .classed('link', true)
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow-head)') // add in the marker-end defined above
    link.exit().remove()

    let node = gA.svg.selectAll('.node').data(gA.force.nodes(), gA.node_id)
        let node_group = node.enter().append('g')
            .classed('node', true)
            .call(gA.drag)
        node_group.append('circle')
            .classed('node-circle', true)
            .attr('r', gA.node_radius) // we may consider adding the position too. it will get updated on the next tick anyway, so we will only add it here if things look glitchy
            .on('mousedown', mousedown)
            .on('mouseup', mouseup)
            .on(gA.circle_events)
        node_group.append('text') // must appear ABOVE node-circle
            .classed('node-text', true)
    node.exit().remove()

    // UPDATE stuff (things we need to update even if we are not enter()ing the node for the first time
    gA.svg.selectAll('.node-text')
        .text(gA.node_label)
    gA.svg.selectAll('circle')
        .classed(gA.circle_class_conditions)
}
```

`main.py` has the server WebsocketHandler, which gets the most up to date user information and uses it...

```
    def on_message(self, message):
        print('got message: ' + message+"\n")
        ball = json.loads(message)
        user = User(ball['identifier'])

        if ball['command'] == 'print':
            print(ball['message'])

        elif ball['command'] == 'open':
            self.send_absolute_dominion(ball, user)
```

...and so forth...

```
    def request_nodes(self, node_ids, ball, user):
        for node_id in node_ids:
            if node_id not in our_DAG.nodes():
                raise ValueError('The node_id "'+node_id+'" does not exist.')
        ids = set(user.dict['learned_node_ids']).union(set(ball['client_node_ids'])).union(set(node_ids))
        H = our_DAG.subgraph(list(ids))
        dict_graph = H.as_complete_dict()
        self.write_message({
            'command': 'load-graph',
            'new_graph': dict_graph,
        })
```

...and...

```
    def send_absolute_dominion(self, ball, user):
        if user.logged_in:
            print('LOGGED IN')
            learned_ids = user.dict['learned_node_ids']
            ids = list(set(learned_ids).union(set(ball['client_node_ids'])))
```

Again, I'm not asking you to solve it for me.  I need theoretical advice/ideas.  If you ask me to try something out and report the output back to you, I can do that.

UPDATE: I have confirmed that the data in the HTML which lists which nodes the user has learned is NOT updated on reload.  This could mean one of two things: 1. the server is not sending updated data or 2. the browser is caching the old HTML.

`index.html`:

```
<body data-host="{{ host }}" data-user-dict-json-string="{{ user_dict_json_string }}">
```

Comment: It seems only the Google+ login is malfunctioning.  I'll look into it, but in the meantime, you can login with any of the other three providers.  Simply click the provider and then click "login".

Comment: Glitch fixed.  But still no clue about the SVG...

Comment: I am already using incognito mode.  Issue persists.

Comment: Which browser and OS are you using?  I'm pretty sure the vertices appear on firefox.

Comment: i was trying it on chrme,,if this works on ff then mention it in the question and also your oauth breaks again i would say that it would be nice if you can move it in a fiddle..may be people are not able to get any further bcoz of that.

Comment: more over your code is all minified i think its bettr to fiddle it

Comment: Can you put a complete code, where you are facing the issue. I hope it will help to understand clearly. If you can see I had created few examples out of which this may be helpful: http://trafficinviter.com/gallery-effects/animated-headers/

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I have put more detailed information and a link to the code repository.  I am offering a 100 bounty of my reputation as a thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @JafferWilson I think your comment may be spam.  Please elaborate if this is not the case.

Comment: @mareoraft Hey my comment is not a spam.... I just want to help you and ask whether the effect available on the webpage link is what you are asking. If you don't think that this link is helpful then please don't say anything like spam. If you want then you can with the complete gallery I have created and then I can provide you the code you desire.

Comment: Sorry @JafferWilson, my mistake.  Thanks for your help, but it is unrelated to my issue.